# Extend scale of BigDecimal number

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a BigDecimal number and i want to add 0 in some case. when i change scale of a BigDecimal it return me only a subNumber of my BigDecimal number

example :

> BigDecimal c = new
>   BigDecimal(0.1721112427968000094313954596298853517869092775632121988466426373478102735617940027951431710952381083564411002004385868111);
>           System.out.println(c.setScale(120));

it return :

```
0.172111242796800012477831387514015659689903259277343750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

how to return a same number with 0 at last of my BigDecimal number ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are losing precision because your argument to BigDecimal is being truncated to a double. You can overcome this if you pass in the same argument but as a String (put quotes around it)